# How can I obtain the version number of a custom Eclipse feature at runtime?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, version, eclipse-pde

I would like to display the version number of a custom Eclipse feature I am developing in the title bar of its perspective. Is there a way to obtain the version number from the runtime plugin and/or workbench?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
Platform.getBundle("my.feature.id").getHeaders().get("Bundle-Version");
```

should do the trick.

Note ([from this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg29801.html)) that it can not be used anywhere *within* the plugin itself:
`this.getBundle()` is not valid until AFTER `super.start(BundleContext)` has been called on your plugin.
So if you are using `this.getBundle()` within your constructor or within your `start(BundleContext)` before calling `super.start()` then it will return null.

---

If that fails, you have here a [more complete "version"](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg48220.html):

```
public static String getPlatformVersion() {
  String version = null;

  try {
    Dictionary dictionary = 
      org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getBundle().getHeaders();
    version = (String) dictionary.get("Bundle-Version"); //$NON-NLS-1$
  } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
    version = getProductVersion();
  }

  return version;
}

public static String getProductVersion() {
  String version = null;

  try {
    // this approach fails in "Rational Application Developer 6.0.1"
    IProduct product = Platform.getProduct();
    String aboutText = product.getProperty("aboutText"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    String pattern = "Version: (.*)\n"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(aboutText);
    boolean found = m.find();

    if (found) {
      version = m.group(1);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }

  return version;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, this works for plugins but not for features. I'm not sure there's a way of getting the version for features.

Answer (score 1):

I use the first option:

```
protected void fillStatusLine(IStatusLineManager statusLine) {
    statusItem = new StatusLineContributionItem("LastModificationDate"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    statusItem.setText("Ultima Actualizaci\u00f3n: "); //$NON-NLS-1$
    statusLine.add(statusItem);
    Dictionary<String, String> directory = Platform.getBundle("ar.com.cse.balanza.core").getHeaders();
    String version = directory.get("Bundle-Version");

    statusItem = new StatusLineContributionItem("CopyRight"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    statusItem.setText(Messages.AppActionBar_18);
    statusLine.add(statusItem);
}
```

Comment: even better:     String version = Platform.getBundle("ar.com.cse.balanza.core").getVersion().toString();

Answer (score 0):

As @zvikico says above, the accepted answer does not work for Features, only Plug-ins (OSGi Bundles, which Features are not). The way to get info about installed features is via `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundleGroupProviders()` as [described here](http://vladdu.blogspot.com/2010/06/retrieving-features-version-number-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

A version of what VonC provided to retrieve the primary Eclipse version number, but one that doesn't reference internal classes (which you should avoid doing):

```
Platform.getBundle(PlatformUI.PLUGIN_ID).getHeaders().get("Bundle-Version");
```