# How to obtain the version of a custom feature at runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, version, eclipse-rcp

There is a similar question [on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817299/how-can-i-obtain-the-version-number-of-a-custom-eclipse-feature-at-runtime), but the answers only work for detecting the versions of available plug-ins.

I however look for a way to retrieve the version number of a user-defined feature at runtime.

Let's say I defined a feature `com.me.prog.prod.feature` that defines plugin dependencies and is later used in a product definition `com.me.prog.prod.product`. When launching `com.me.prog.prod.product` I want to be able to retrieve the version information of `com.me.prog.prod.feature` as I want to use it for top-level program versioning.

Is there a way to do this using Eclipse RCP framework code?

Answer (score 2):

The following should get you the feature version number:

```
String version = null;
IBundleGroupProvider[] providers = Platform.getBundleGroupProviders();
for (IBundleGroupProvider provider : providers) {
    IBundleGroup[] groups = provider.getBundleGroups();
    for (IBundleGroup group : groups) {
        if ("com.me.prog.prod.feature".equals(group.getIdentifier())) {
            version = group.getVersion();
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to give the specific feature name in there as a plugin could potentially belong to more than one feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. While your code neatly lists a number of features provided by the platform (eclipse.rcp, emf, eclipse.help), any user-defined features are not present.

Comment: I have test projects set up with a custom product and feature. If I export the product from the product editor the above code shows the custom feature (although it doesn't when run through the Eclipse launcher). There also seem to be a number of other configuration settings that could cause the feature not to be listed, such as not entering the branding plugin in the feature.xml.